# How to set custom text to a GroupRow in the CustomDrawGroupRow event of a DevExpress GridControl?

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I'm looking for a way of setting the `GroupRow` text inside the `CustomDrawGroupRow` event without setting `e.Handled = true` because I need the base drawing to also be applied:

```
this.gridView.CustomDrawGroupRow += (s, e) => 
{
    /* set the GroupRow text here without using e.Handled = true */
}
```

I've tried using `e.Graphics.DrawString` but then I can't use `e.Appearance.BackColor` because I need to set `e.Handled = true` to draw the `string` which disables it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the `e.Info` as `GridGroupRowInfo` and set `GridGroupRowInfo.GroupText` to your value:

```
using DevExprss.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.ViewInfo;

...

this.gridView.CustomDrawGroupRow += (s, e) => 
{
    GridGroupRowInfo groupInfo = e.Info as GridGroupRowInfo;
    groupInfo.GroupText = "Custom group text";
}
```